# How to slide aside a modal - revealing other modal (wizard like...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate, modal-dialog

At the following fiddle I've implemented two modals that act like a wizard:

```
$('#jumptosecondmodal').click(function(e) {
    $('#secondmodal').modal('show');
    $('#firstmodal').modal('hide');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nV8XZ/show

http://jsfiddle.net/nV8XZ/

Instead of switching between the modals (show/hide), I need to animate the first modal aside until disappearing, revealing the second modal.

Edit:

I've managed to implement the sliding, but it works as expected only for the first run. Consecutive runs doesn't slide but toggle (until page refreshing)

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/nV8XZ/22

Edit2:

Thanks ridecar2 for the help,

And here is a enhanced working version:

http://jsfiddle.net/nV8XZ/27/show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your later jsFiddle you need to do:

```
$('#jumptosecondmodal').click(function(e) {
  $('#secondmodal').width('1px');
  $('#secondmodal').modal('show');
  $('#secondmodal').animate({width: 400}, 2500, function(){
    $('#firstmodal').modal('hide');
  })
})
```

`$('#secondmodal').width('1px');` is the important line as it sets the width of the second modal area back to 1px each time you use it.

Comment: Great, thanks! But - why $('#secondmodal').addClass('my_width');  where: .my_width {width: 1px; } - that I added to closeModal function didn't worked?

Comment: My guess is that the animate method sets the width inline, this will override the setting from a class unless the `!important` directive is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods:

```
$('#jumptosecondmodal').click(function(e) {
    $('#firstmodal').fadeOut(400, function(){
        $(this).modal('hide')
        $('#secondmodal').fadeIn().modal('show')
    })
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nV8XZ/1/)

Comment: Nice, but this is not what I need. I want to see the first modal sliding aside. Thanks anyway!